# How to resize window to dialog size in Fyne

Tags: user-interface, go, fyne

I am using the Fyne package for Go. All I want to do is display a dialog, and have the window automatically resize to the maximum size of the dialog. I've gone over the documentation and looked at examples but I can't find it anywhere! The window is always 0x0 pixels. If I resize the window out I can tell that the dialog has a maximum height and width but I can't seem to feed that back into the size of the window. Here is my code:

```
import (
    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/dialog"
)

var myApp fyne.App

func main() {
    myApp = app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("test")

    cnfm := dialog.NewConfirm("Test Dialog!", "Are you sure you want to interact with this test dialog?", loseCallback, myWindow)

    cnfm.Show()
    cnfm.Resize(cnfm.MaxSize())

    myWindow.Show()
    
    // uncomment to have a window greater than 0x0
    //myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(375, 180))
    myApp.Run()
}

func loseCallback(yes bool) {
    myApp.Quit()
}
```

This seems really basic but I just can't find any way to achieve this! I've tried playing with layouts, containers, etc but nothing makes a difference, the window is always 0x0. I would really appreciate some help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fyne doesn't really have a concept of MaxSize. There is MinSize() (what a component should never be smaller than) and it's Size() which is the current size on screen.
Dialogs appear over the current content so are not constrained, or expaneded, by the content layout etc.

As a dialog is not designed to be the main content of a while I wonder if changing your content to be inside the window would be more suitable (as the dialog is really used when something in the app is happening and you want to interrupt it).

For example:

```
import (
    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

var myApp fyne.App

func main() {
    myApp = app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("test")

    yes := widget.NewButton("Yes", closeCallback)
    yes.Importance = widget.HighImportance
    myWindow.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
        widget.NewLabel("Are you sure you want to interact with this test dialog?"),
        container.NewHBox(layout.NewSpacer(),
            widget.NewButton("No", closeCallback), yes,
            layout.NewSpacer())))

    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}

func closeCallback() {
    myApp.Quit()
}
```